# Search for a site with problems

Tags: math

I saw in the past a question someone asked for a way to learn some programming language and one answer was with a link to a site with a lot of problems and solutions by other programmers.

There was a problem like: "print the Fibonacci series"... and so on...

Unfortunately I can't remember the sites name to URL...

May you know the site I am talking about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean [The Euler Project](http://projecteuler.net/)?